# How set background gradient for button with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, graphics

Hi I wanna set set background gradient for button with kotlin in programming not use XML

how I can create it ?

like this

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDHhN.png)

Comment: and what did you do so far?
Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort from you to solve your own problem before asking a question. SO is not a free coding service, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with your written code.  Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use XML, then you'll have to at least include an image asset that contains such background into the `drawable` folder of your application.

Once you do that, it should be as simple as calling

```
yourImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.you_background_image_asset)
```

Comment: I want change value of gradient in run time